# Check contents of response to json request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to build a random quote generator as per the FreeCodeCamp challenge, but I wanted to begin by just writing a test to confirm I'm actually getting the json object I'm requesting. I have a simple h1 element with the id set to 'quote' and the following code (jQuery is loaded up in the CodePen)

```
function genQuote () {
  var output = $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(data){
    var theQuote = data.content;
    var Author = data.title;

    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = theQuote;
  });
}
```

The url in question, when visited, shows what looks plainly like a json object, to me, but my function does not change the #quote item at all.

Comment: lookup CORS - check your browser developer tools console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `&callback=` from URL, to request `JSON`, instead of converting `$.getJSON()` call to `jsonp` request. Also, an array is returned, not a plain object; access the object using bracket notation

```
function genQuote () {
  var output = $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", function(data){

    var theQuote = data[0].content;
    var Author = data[0].title;

    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = theQuote;
  })
}

$(genQuote);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gpyx6jLy/

Answer (score 0):

As the comment to your question says, this is a Cross Origin Request Sharing (CORS) issue. The API is returning "http://null" as the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, which disallows your access.

It looks like this is a bug in their API server, and you probably won't be able to use it.

Comment: The issue is that `javascript` at Question is making a `jsonp` request, not a request for `JSON`.  stacksnippets has `null` origin, not URL passed as parameter to `$.getJSON()`. Protocol of request origin and URL should also match.